# What's the difference between "attend" and "enrol"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I think both of them use for official registration. for example in a high school.

1. He had always dreamed of attending college abroad.
2. My father enrolled me in elementary school.

Comment: 'Going to school' has a more stative, habitual sense as well as the more active or punctive one. 'Johnny is going to school in ten minutes' shows the more active usage, whereas 'Johnny has been going to school since September' shows the more stative sense. 'Attending' is used almost solely with a more stative sense; 'Johnny had always dreamed of going to a college in Elbonia'. Not 'Johnny is attending school in ten minutes.' //  'Enrol' can be found in any dictionary.

Comment: Nowadays, with smartphones and the Internet, there is no excuse for not knowing what a word means, so everyone should look up words in at least two different online dictionaries before posting a question about meaning. There are no excuses. None. Unless you explain "why" you are confused. Saying "I think" without first checking is a bit rude in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could be enrolled for something and be waiting to attend the event.

> 'He enrolled in a course which begins after the summer. He is now holidaying in the Bahamas. He starts the course in September and will be attending college for two years.'

Answer (score 2):

In British usage at least, to enrol on a course means to join, to start.

To attend a course means to regualrly come to it.