# Did he really write 'punctive'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

A highly respected person, with a very exemplary reputation, has just commented on EL : [Comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414193/whats-the-difference-of-attend-and-enroll) 'a more stative, habitual sense as well as the more active or *punctive* one.'

I had never seen the word 'punctive' so I looked it up; or I tried to look it up.
Google forces me to accept 'punitive'. The Oxford Dictionary of English doesn't list it.

If it is not a word, then it should be; I like the sound of it. But if it exists and is not just a typo for 'punitive' then how is punctive different from punctual ?

Comment: I think you've already discovered the answer: the word doesn't exist. And the very few people (if any) who think it exists  and is different from "punctual" probably disagree on its actual meaning.

Comment: I am heartbroken. I was longing to use it.

Comment: Actually, looking in the OED, they say it's obsolete and rare, (which I think means it was rare before it became obsolete). They give one (!) citation. "1612   R. Daborn: *Christian turn'd Turke* Who like a ship unman'd..doth seeme to make a course Direct and punctive, till we see it dash Against some prouder Sylla." And they seem to have guessed the definition from that one use, so your guess as to what it means might be as good as theirs.

Comment: @PeterShor In that case I intend to use it frequently and mysteriously to gasps of admiration.

Comment: I think it's a linguistics term. Here's [an example](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=1A0rBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=linguistics+punctive&source=bl&ots=oqTGCnTXu6&sig=FW-tXqgGvryt9F7GME9AFdogmGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAq_LMgPDWAhVCi7wKHcDGCJ0Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=linguistics%20punctive&f=false) of its use.

Comment: [Realms of Meaning: An Introduction to Semantics_T R. Hofmann](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7cKOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT175&lpg=PT175&dq=punctive+meaning&source=bl&ots=LRaP2j3FEP&sig=mmRGAuyKAQiohI8ZE6k47a4KsAU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1KiPgPDWAhXEuRoKHSTpCbwQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=punctive%20meaning&f=false) is a 1993 grammar using the word. As does [this 2016 article by Wittenberg & Levy](http://www.mit.edu/~rplevy/papers/wittenberg-levy-2017-jml-quick-kiss.pdf) (p 4). And many others. @Peter is looking in the wrong places for metalanguage. Rather disappointing. ('Punctual' causes other problems.)

Comment: OED is also disappointing if one has to try to interpret {'obsolete' _and_ 'rare'}. // The Hofmann book is somewhere along the semanto-syntactic continuum, probably near the middle.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth After all this I still can't figure out what 'punctive' is supposed to mean. The context doesn't have enough to make it more specific. I am inclined to allow it, but it'd be nice to know what was intended.

Comment: @Mitch The more usual term for a verb referencing 'happening at a point in time' (broadened of course to 'happening at what is usefully considered vitually a point in time' [like a blink] or even 'happening at what is usefully considered a point in time' [perhaps _Bleriot had flown across the Channel] is 'punctual'.  Iterative events can be punctual. // 'Punctual' has such a strong default sense that I prefer to use 'punctive' after Hofmann, but especially Wittenberg, & Levy.

Comment: ... [Wittenberg & Levy__If you want a quick kiss, make it count: How choice of syntactic
construction affects event construal___Journal of Memory and Language_2017](http://www.mit.edu/~rplevy/papers/wittenberg-levy-2017-jml-quick-kiss.pdf)<< In our
study of punctive and durative events, we use light verb constructions with give, which is itself telic (Newman, 1996).
**The mass–count distinction and verbal aspect** >>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Punctive* simply means "of or relating to a point in time".

It **is** listed in OED, albeit as "obsolete" and in an unrelated meaning:

> Apparently: directed straight towards a particular point.

In the comment referred to, it is to be contrasted with *durative*, as Thomas R Hoffman explains in *Realms of Meaning: An Introduction to Semantics* (Taylor & Francis, 2015):

[image: image of book]

> Contrary to the stative nature of most adjectives and perhaps all nouns, verbs commonly depict events that have beginnings and ends. If the end must follow on the heels of the beginning, we call the verb ***punctive*** [as in the word *puncture*) or ‘punctual’. Sometimes the term ‘punctive’ is restricted to [some verbs] where conceptually at least B = F [Beginning = Finish]. It is quite hard to imagine a circumstance where the progressive could be used with them, e.g. * ‘Finally he is recognizing me.’ If on the other hand the end is necessarily long after the beginning, the verb is called ***durative*** (like the words *duration, during*).

Hoffmann lists some punctive verbs as *notice, recognize, arrive, find, explode, hit, begin, wake up.*

The comment OP refers to uses "[is] going to school" as an example, which is difficult to conceptualise as punctive, I feel, simply because the main verb is *is.* But yes, he really did write *punctive,* and did intend it to have this "instantaneous" meaning.

Comment: So to be clear, it is obsolete and or rare in the general publc, but is well-understood technical jargon among some linguists studying verbs.